# How to change HTTP Basic Authentication form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, basic-authentication

For HTTP Basic Authentication I need a custom form which has fields like `site block` and `site password` instead of `username` and `password`. I just want the text to be changed from username to site block and password to site password.

Reference for standard form: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the name of the fields. [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is part of the HTTP specification and therefore the functionality is hardcoded into the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't easily use Rails' built in `HttpAuthentication::Basic` class to do this, or at least there is not a straightforward way to configure the fields that are to be used for credentials like you would with something like `devise`. It is hardcoded to use encoded username/password fields to build an encoded authorization hash based on them.

See this source code/example: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fbe2433be6e052a1acac63c7faf287c52ed3c5ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb

The supplied username/password are encoded into a `WWW-Authentication` header, which is then used to generate a token, which is based on hashed user/password values.

Basic auth is basic auth. In order to do something that isn't so basic you would have to roll your own.

You may be able to capture the form values in your controller action and do something like:

```
user = params[:site_block]
password = params[:site_password]
```

...and then perform a custom authentication process based on those variables

Here is a workable example which would require some tweaking, but illustrates the point:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html